# Is it safe to reduce TFS DB size by using Delete stored procedures?

Tags: tfs

We have TFS 2017.3 and the database it's huge - about 1.6 **TB**.

I want to try to clean up the space by running these 2 stored procedures:

- prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent
- prc_DeleteUnusedFiles
- prc_DeleteUnusedContent

Is it safe to run it?
Is there a chance that it will delete important things I am currently using? (of course, I will do a backup before...)

What are the best values to put in these stored procedures?

Another thing - If I run this query:

```
SELECT A.[ResourceId]  
FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Content] As A
left join [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_FileMetadata] As B on A.ResourceId=B.ResourceId
where B.[ResourceId] IS Null
```

I got result of 10681.
If I run this query:

```
SELECT A.[ResourceId]  
FROM PTU_NICE_Coll.[dbo].[tbl_Content] As A
left join PTU_NICE_Coll.[dbo].tbl_FileReference As B on A.ResourceId=B.ResourceId
where B.[ResourceId] IS Null
```

I got result of 10896.

How can I remove this rows? and is it completely safe to remove them?

Answer (score 4):

Generally we don't recommend to do actions against the DB directly as it may cause problems.

However if you have to do that, then you need to **backup the DBs** first.

You can refer to below articles to clean up and reduce the size of the TFS databases:

- [Control\Reduce TFS DB Size](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2014/06/29/controlreduce-tfs-db-size/)
- [Cleaning up and reduce the size of the TFS database](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/cleaning-up-and-reduce-the-size-of-the-tfs-database/)
- [Clean up your Team Project Collection](https://blog.jessehouwing.nl/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/)

> Another option is to dive deep into the database, and run the cleanup
>   stored procedures manually. If your Content table is large:
>
> ```
> EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedContent 1
> ```
>
> If your Files table is large:
>
> ```
> EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 1000
> ```
>
> This second sproc may run for a long time, that’s why it has the third
>   parameter which defines the batch size. You should run this sprocs
>   multiple times, or if it completes quickly, you can increase the chunk
>   size.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you. the third article maybe can help me. our huge table is tbl_content (so the issue is not attachments). if I run the stored procedures, am I need to shrink the DB after?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Generally you just need to delete the unused repo/files from TFS, the metadata and files will get cleaned up when you run the stored procedures. So in this point you don't need to shrink the DB any more after that.

Comment: I tried to run it few times but it's finished super fast and not reduce the DB size :/

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Have you resolved the issue? What about increasing the chunk size if it completes quickly as mentioned in above answer?

Comment: I tried also to increase the chunk size, the same results.