# Why tbl_Content is so huge from the beginning?

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops-server

I've installed Azure DevOps Server on a machine and it's a very fresh installation. I created a Team Project Collection in it, and in that I created a simple Team Project. And I connected to it, got the latest version, created a simple .NET project and checked it in.

So, no single line of code is written in it yet.

But when I created the backup plan for Azure DevOps databases, I realized that `AzureDevOps_Configuration` database has a table called `dbo.tbl_Content` that is taking near 750 MB of disk space.

And the data is a binary data in this table.

Why this table takes that much space from the beginning? What it contains? How to reduce its size?

Comment: Looks like this table is huge in most of the scenarios, maybe you can get some help from [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809690/10910450) to reduce the growing size.

Comment: In most project collections, the content will have things like test attachments or work item attachments and I think even test point history is there.  I'm not positive about the Configuration, seems like required items or backend processes?  On some of the actual projects though, managing retention, we've had this table size grow to > 6TB, so  in comparison ... less than 1GB isn't really huge.